# how to construct filter string in datatable compute() avg?

Tags: c#, filter, average, outliers

I am trying to compute average of a column in a datatable RefdtClone.
The data varies quite a bit, and I want to exclude data that is excessively large, for example exclude value > 9999. I can't seem to find information about how to construct the filter string as part of the compute() argument. Any help is appreciated.

My code is as follows.

```
string dataColumnName = "";
string filter =""; // I want to exclude value > 9999 from compute() avg
dataColumnName = (string)RefdtClone.Columns[firstDataColumn + i].ColumnName;
ComputeAVGColumn = String.Concat("AVG(["+ dataColumnName+ "])");
Analysisdt.Rows[i]["Mean 1"] = RefdtClone.Compute(ComputeAVGColumn, filter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string dataColumnName = (string)RefdtClone.Columns[firstDataColumn + i].ColumnName;
ComputeAVGColumn = String.Concat("AVG(["+ dataColumnName+ "])");
string filter = String.Format("[{0}] <= 9999", dataColumnName);
Analysisdt.Rows[i]["Mean 1"] = RefdtClone.Compute(ComputeAVGColumn, filter);
```

syntax for filter is described on [MSDN DataColumn.Expression page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.90).aspx)